# Python dot notation method attributes VS other methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, why are some built-in functions called using brackets with the method name before the object, e.g.

```
print("foobar")
bool("foobar")
...
```

While others are built-in method attributes, called with a dot behind the object, e.g.

```
"foobar".capitalize()
```

Specifically I'm interested to learn if there is a general principle behind this instead of just common practice and memorization. In cases where you can't quite remember whether it was capitalize("foobar") or "foobar".capitalize(), how do you know?

Comment: Does it make sense to `print` an integer? Does it make sense to `print` a dictionary? Does it make sense to  `capitalize` an integer? Does it make sense to  `capitalize` a dictionary?

Comment: The `builtin` methods are not specific to any data type and are usually able to be performed on anything like `len()`. However, something like `str.title()` is specific to string so it would not make any sense to do `title(1836)` since that wouldn't do anything since it's a number